# No leak on thrown constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

According to `valgrind` the following code does *not* contain memory leaks:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace {

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo();
};

Foo::Foo() { throw std::runtime_error("This is an error"); }

}  // anonymous namespace

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  try {
    new Foo();
  } catch (const std::exception& aError) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Indeed. the result of `valgrind --leak-check=full` is:

```
==25913== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25913== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25913== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25913== Command: ./test
==25913== 
==25913== 
==25913== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25913==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25913==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 72,890 bytes allocated
==25913== 
==25913== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25913== 
==25913== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25913== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The program is compiled with `g++ (GCC) 7.3.0`.

**Note:** there is no leak even with `clang 5.0.1`.

**Note:** I checked the disassembly code and there is `delete` call.

---

**My question:** why this code does not produce memory leak? Is it really something specified in the standard (can you link?) or just autonomous compiler enhancement?

---

**What I expect**:

```
...
call operator new(unsigned long)
mov rbx, rax
mov rdi, rbx
call (anonymous namespace)::Foo::Foo()
```

The dynamic allocation happens, after the call to the constructor which throws producing leak.

Comment: `Foo()` throws, so the idea is that *before* the `unique_ptr` is constructed, the constructor would throw. So you allocate memory, but don't pass it to the `unique_ptr`, which should mean that it leaks. @John3136

Comment: @John3136 A) *As I've written*, **even without smart pointer** (a simple `new`) produces the **same** result. B) You have no idea how `smart pointers` are built. (see why standard introduces `std::make_unique`, instead of use `new`). Please be careful before to comment

Comment: Maybe you should change your question to not mention smart pointers, it's pretty confusing how you seem to make it all about smart pointers and then mention in a note that actually it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: 'My question: why this code does not produce memory leak?' Questions of that type can be translated, "Guess what my misconception is, and refute it."

Comment: Well, smart pointer does not mean *no memory leaks*. Anyway, I can easily change the question avoiding them

Comment: @JiveDadson Yeah, what's wrong with that? I know there is something that I am missing and I am asking for that piece of knowledge, simple as that.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: _"Well, smart pointer does not mean no memory leaks."_ It should.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: FWIW, Jive was complaining about the "guess" part. We can't tell you what's wrong with your idea until we know what that idea is. A lot of people just say "why does this code do _X_?", forgetting to tell us what they expected instead. Although in this particular case I think it's pretty obvious from the question, so...

Comment: It's impossible for this code to leak a `Foo` since no `Foo` is ever successfully created. I'm puzzled what someone would even think it could potentially leak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case the constructor throws an exception, the memory will not leak, because an allocator must deallocate the memory before passing the exception, if there is a appropriate deallocation function.

According to the [March 2017 Working Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> **8.3.4 New [expr.new]**
>
> 20 If the *new-expression* creates an object or an array of objects of class type, access and ambiguity control
>   are done for the allocation function, the deallocation function (15.5), and the constructor (15.1). If the
>   *new-expression* creates an array of objects of class type, the destructor is potentially invoked (15.4).
>
> 21 If any part of the object initialization described above<sup>80</sup> terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable
>   deallocation function can be found, **the deallocation function is called to free the memory** in which the object
>   was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression.
>   **If no unambiguous matching deallocation function can be found, propagating the exception does not cause
>   the object’s memory to be freed.** [ Note: This is appropriate when the called allocation function does not
>   allocate memory; otherwise, it is likely to result in a memory leak. — end note ]
>
> <sup>80)</sup> This may include evaluating a *new-initializer* and/or calling a constructor

Also, according to the [Exceptions FAQ in the C++ wiki](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#why-exceptions):

> *“But throwing an exception from a constructor invoked by `new` causes a memory leak!”* Nonsense! That’s an old-wives’ tale caused by a bug in one compiler – and that bug was immediately fixed over a decade ago.

Comment: That's nice. Do you extend your answer linking something from the standard? I understand it's a nonsense, but technically speaking it should produce a leak, unless if otherwise specified

Comment: [cppreference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction)

Comment: @BiagioFesta C++ Standard link: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#21

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Your attention to rigour is admirable. Of course, if `new` could leak like this then C++ would be horribly broken ;)

Comment: @Firefrost: Now I'm wondering what and when compiler that was! I'd almost put money on that text itself being over a decade old now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's an interesting question. Unfortunately, I couldn't find out which compiler was affected.

Comment: @Firefrost: Me neither :(